# Some Screenshots on iTunes Connect not appearing

Tags: iphone, xcode, screenshot, app-store-connect

I can successfully upload five iphone / ipod touch screenshots to itunes connect. I have always kept the screenshots the same resolution, whether five at all 320 by 480, or five at 640 by 960. I dont mix the resolutions. I have tried from different browsers, including chrome, firefox, and safari, and from different computers and internet connections. The same result happens. I see all five, and I can log off and log back in to iTunes connect ans still see all five. But after about 15-30 minutes, when I log back in I only see the first and last screenshot. So I see two screenshots instead of five. I have been working with contact us at itunes support but no resolution has happened yet. Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a fix?

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar. Have you figured it out??

Comment: I cant fix it at all. I can upload five fine and see them still but it reverts now back to one screenshots after 20 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with iTunes Connect synchronizing the screenshots to the various download servers. You have to contact Developer Technical Support to get that looked at.